# TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not TextIOWrapper couldnt be solved

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I want to open a file and then convert it from docx to zip. I am experiencing a blockade however with the selected file variable with the error of the title. "selected_file" in last line is highlighted as the bug in my IDE. Please know I am a beginner. My code is below:

```
import zipfile
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
tk.Tk().withdraw()

fn = askopenfilename(initialdir='/Desktop', title='Select a file', filetypes=(('docx file', '*.docx'), ('All files', '*.*')))

selected_file = open(fn)

with open(os.path.splitext(selected_file)[0] + '.zip')
```

Comment: Your code is a little unclear. First you get the filename with `askopenfilename`, then you `open` the file, then you try to split the _already open_ file itself (not the filename or filepath) and...reopen it again with the zip extension? Shouldn't you be calling the last step directly on the result of askopenfilename?

Comment: On the result of askopenfilename? Can you please clarify? Perhaps in code?

Comment: Do you mean "print"?

Comment: What is the intent of ```with open(os.path.splitext(selected_file)[0] + '.zip')```  This is an incomplete python statement.  If the intent is to convert the file to a "zip" file, simply changing the extension doesn't do that..  ```selected_file```  is a file object, not file contents.  So what is it you are trying to do?

Comment: @G.Anderson please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure what you want.  Note that a .docx file *is* just a ZIP file containing (mostly) XML files.  The code below will open a dialog on the current directory to select a DOCX file and list the files in the archive:

```py
import zipfile
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

fn = askopenfilename(title='Select a file', filetypes=(('docx file', '*.docx'), ('All files', '*.*')))

with zipfile.ZipFile(fn) as z:
    for file in z.namelist():
        print(file)
```

Running this and selecting a DOCX file I had returns:

```
[Content_Types].xml
_rels/.rels
word/document.xml
word/_rels/document.xml.rels
word/theme/theme1.xml
word/settings.xml
word/styles.xml
word/webSettings.xml
word/fontTable.xml
docProps/core.xml
docProps/app.xml
```